# Merge two dictionaries' values by keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I want to merge two dictionaries' values if the keys are the same.

```
DIC_01
{'A': ['Zero'],
 'B': ['Zero'],
 'C': ['Zero'],
 'D': ['Zero']}

DIC_02
 {'A': [2338.099365234375,
  -3633.070068359375,
  -73.45938873291016],
 'D':[2839.291015625,
  -2248.350341796875,
  1557.59423828125]}
```

Idea output

```
{'A': [[2338.099365234375,
-3633.070068359375,
-73.45938873291016],['Zero']],
'D': [[2839.291015625,
-2248.350341796875,
1557.59423828125]['Zero']]}
```

Output for the Keys that cannot be found

```
{'B': ['Zero'],'C': ['Zero']}
```

I tried

```
NO_MATCH={}
for k in DIC_01.keys():
    DOC={}
    for k2 in DIC_02.keys():
        if k == k2:
            DOC = k.values().update(k2.values())
        else:
            NO_MATCH.update(DIC_01)
```

There is nothing in DOC and all the dictionary elements are in NO_MATCH, no error message. don't know where goes wrong, also I think there must be better ways to do this.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want one dict for the output,  or two separate dicts?

Comment: @DYZ I researched online but haven't found a way to give me the output i want.

Comment: @wim  I want one dictionary for matched key found, and another one for no matched key found.

Comment: There is nothing to research here, just use your programming skills. SO is not a free coding service, you must demostrate your effort to get help.

Comment: DIC.update() modifies DIC in place and returns None, so your DOC = None

Comment: Hint: `D1.keys() & D2.keys()` gives keys that are in both dicts.  `D1.keys() - D2.keys()` gives keys that are only in D1 dict.

Comment: @kenbroon thanks. I tried append and extend but dictionary doesn't have these functions. Which function should I use to extend value into another dictionary?

Comment: @takkyi83 See my answer below! I just updated it to point out errors in your loop and added a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: You can declare two separate dictionaries and iterate through all the keys of both dictionaries. For every iteration, check if the key exists in `DIC_02` and `DIC_01` and concatenate the two corresponding lists

```
match, no_match = {}, {}
for i in {**DIC_01,**DIC_02}.keys():
    if i in DIC_01 and i in DIC_02:
        match[i] = DIC_01[i] + DIC_02[i]
    else:
        no_match[i] = DIC_01.get(i,[]) + DIC_02.get(i,[])
```

Comment: What happens if `DIC_02` (I assume the smaller of the two dicts) has a key that `DIC_01` does not have?

i.e. `DIC_01 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2} and DIC_02 = {'c': 1}`

Comment: @kingkupps Thanks for catching that! I updated my code, although I still assumed all the dict values are lists

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly fancy but this should solve what you're looking for

```
def merge(a, b):
  out = {}
  for key in a.keys() | b.keys():
    if key in a and key in b:
      out[key] = [a[key], b[key]]
    elif key in a:
      out[key] = a[key]
    else:
      out[key] = b[key]
  return out
```

where `a` and `b` are `dict`s. The `|` takes the union of the two key sets.

Answer (score 0):

> As for why your code goes wrong.

```
NO_MATCH={}
for k in DIC_01.keys():
    DOC={}                   # (1)
    for k2 in DIC_02.keys(): # (2)
        if k == k2:
            DOC = k.values().update(k2.values()) # (3)
        else:
            NO_MATCH.update(DIC_01) # (4)
```

1. Not there! Everything you define inside a loop, will be redefined everytime the loop goes around.
2. This goes to the else block even if there's a matched key. For instance, in your case, it compares `A` in `DIC_01` with `A` in `DIC_02`, `"ok, A matched"`. BUT, then it proceeds to compare `A` in `DIC_01` with `D` in `DIC_02`, `"ok, A not found in DIC_02, not matched, add to NOT_MATCH"` which is wrong, because `A` IS a matched key and `A` IS in `DIC_02`.
3. Not sure how you didn't get an error, seems very erroneous.
4. This lines add the entire `DIC_01` to `NO_MATCH`, wrong!

***FIX:***

```
MATCH = {}
NO_MATCH = {}

# This goes through all keys in DIC_01. If a key is also found in DIC_02,
# it's a "matched" key so it adds that key to the MATCH variable. If it's
# not in DIC_02, it's a "no matched" key -> add key to NO_MATCH variable.
for k in DIC_01.keys():
    if k in DIC_02.keys():
        MATCH[k] = [DIC_01[k], DIC_02[k]]
    else:
        NO_MATCH[k] = DIC_01[k]

# BUT...We are still missing the keys that are only in DIC_02. So we need
# another loop
for k in DIC_02.keys():
    if k not in DIC_01.keys():
        NO_MATCH[k] = DIC_02[k]
# This is the same as the loop above, without the if block.
```

> ***BETTER WAY***

Some list comprehensions would keep things clean.

```
MATCH = {key:[DIC_01[key], DIC_02[key]] for key in DIC_01 if key in DIC_02}

unmatch_1 = {key:DIC_01[key] for key in DIC_01 if key not in DIC_02}
unmatch_2 = {key:DIC_02[key] for key in DIC_02 if key not in DIC_01}
NOT_MATCH = {**unmatch_1, **unmatch_2}
```

***EXPLAINATION:***

```
MATCH = {key:[DIC_01[key], DIC_02[key]] for key in DIC_01 if key in DIC_02}
```

This, in English, create a new dictionary called `match`.For every key in `DIC_01`, if the key is also in `DIC_02`, create the same key in `match` and assign both the values of that key from `DIC_01` and `DIC_02`.

```
unmatch_1 = {key:DIC_01[key] for key in DIC_01 if key not in DIC_02}
```

This ... For every key in `DIC_01`, if it's not in `DIC_02`, create a key and assign the associated value from `DIC_01`

```
unmatch_2 = {key:DIC_02[key] for key in DIC_02 if key not in DIC_01}
```

This ... For every key in `DIC_02`, if it's not in `DIC_01`, create a key and assign the associated value from `DIC_02`

```
UNMATCH = {**unmatch_1, **unmatch_2}
```

This ... is a cool way of merging 2 dictionaries (Only for Python 3.5 and up)

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a great use for [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)

```html
>>> a={'A': ['Zero'],
...  'B': ['Zero'],
...  'C': ['Zero'],
...  'D': ['Zero']}
>>> b={'A': [2338.099365234375,
...   -3633.070068359375,
...   -73.45938873291016],
...  'D':[2839.291015625,
...   -2248.350341796875,
...   1557.59423828125]}
>>> map=ChainMap(b,a)
>>> map['A']
[2338.099365234375, -3633.070068359375, -73.45938873291016]
>>> map['C']
['Zero']
```

The key precedence will be on the order of the dictionaries, so if you can't control order or if the `['Zero']` are mixed and matched: this way can't help.